# ¿Como puedo mandar un string a Arduino usando una shield NFC?

Tags: android-studio, arduino, nfc

Estoy intentando abrir una cerradura electrónica con Arduino, una Shield NFC y mi dispositivo móvil.
He diseñado una app en Android Studio en la que debo de introducir una combinación de 5 dígitos y activar la sincronización NFC para enviarle los datos a la Shield NFC.
Me gustaría saber la manera en la que puedo mandar esos digitos desde Java a Arduino y recibirlos en este usando la tarjeta NFC.

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos.

Comment: Que shield nfc estas usando con arduino? Hay algunas que no soportan la comunicación con los smartphones.